# Jsoup does not read/load entire page

Tags: jsoup

http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderListResults.aspx?letter=A

It appears that some content is loaded later, after jsoup reads page ?
There is no "Abelia chinensis" in doc.html() or there is no any of other elements  from list

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderListResults.aspx?letter=A")
        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21")
        .ignoreContentType(true)               
        .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
        .followRedirects(true)
        .timeout(600000)
        .maxBodySize(0)/*unlimited body size*/
        .get();  

    responseBody =  doc.html();
```

Comment: hmm tested here: https://try.jsoup.org/~kjnlfvCzrxiqaGQqwcszLZswSNg and here it works...

Answer (score 0):

`Abelia chinensis` is there, but you may have missed it because the HTML is strangely built like this:

```
<i>Abelia</i> <i>chinensis</i>
```

To select every link with name use:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[id^=MainContentPlaceHolder_SearchResultsList_TaxonName_]");
```

It means select every `<a>` with id starting with `MainContentPlaceHolder_SearchResultsList_TaxonName_`. It selects exactly 821 results.

Comment: Can you tell more about what are you trying to do?

Comment: For some reason I don't get content, coparison of firefox page source/ jsoup doc.html()  </div><div class="row">Your search returned  821 results. ////  <div class="row"><div class="column-left">  jsoup 1.12.1  java 8

Comment: Ahh sorry to all. Messed target link in my code. All works OK.

But server returned something anyway, hence running in circles (-:

Comment: Nice. If you like the answer remember to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).